# Youtube video causes Main View to open afterwards. 

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, youtube

I just implemented a youtube video view on my app, but when I close the youtube video after watching it.. it wont close. It opens the main view controller then places it above all other view controllers (i think). heres how I am showing the youtube video:

Inside MyViewController.m:

```
NSString *lessonHTML = @"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0P7UgKjzndo";

NSString *ytHtml = @"<html><head>\
    <body style=\"margin:0\">\
    <embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
    width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>\
    </body></html>";


    NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:ytHtml, lessonHTML, youtubeView.frame.size.width, youtubeView.frame.size.height];
    NSLog(@"HTML String: %@",html);
    [youtubeView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
```

when the thumbnail is pressed it loads the video. Then when I click 'done' it bring me back to my main ViewController not the one I was in.

Im using Storyboards just incase its something to do with that.

Beer and upvotes for epic answers thanks!

Comment: how do you implement your 'done' button?

Comment: It loads the youtube application. The done button is not implemented by me.

Comment: any solution to this problem?